# How to implement Foreign Key constraint to two different tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Below are the simplified analogous versions of my classes -

```
class AbstractEmployee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'abstract_employee'
    id
    name
    _cls
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_on=_cls, with_polymorphic='*')


class AbstractEngineer(AbstractEmployee):
    factory_number

class ChemicalEngineer(AbstractEngineer):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity='chemical_engineer')    

class AbstractScientist(AbstractEmployee):
    lab_number

class Chemist(AbstractScientist):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity='chemist)
```

Here I am implementing the Single Table Inheritance pattern, where the `abstract_employee` is the only table. Now I have `Company` table as follows

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id
    employee_id
```

Now I want employee_id to be a foreign key which is EITHER in `ChemicalEngineer` OR `Chemist`and not in any other class. One way of doing this is having a Foreign Key constraint on AbstractEmployee.id column and then creating a validation to do a manual check, like -

```
@validates('employee_id')
def check_emp_id(self, key, emp_id):
    assert ChemicalEngineer.get(emp_id) or Chemist.get(emp_id)
```

But is there a better way? This might slow down insert queries.

(For other reasons, I cannot change the class hierarchy. Also there are other classes as well which derive from the Abstract classes which I haven't mentioned)